# GCP Workflow - Managing revisions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to create a deployment strategy for GCP Workflow. I saw that GCP Workflow has the concept of revision.

Can i "route traffic" using the revision concept?
Can I rollback to previous version?
How to test the GCP Workflow? Is there a way to run it locally?

Comment: It's a very expected feature from the community but it's not yet the case. Stay tuned

Comment: I have "solved" using a feat branch model. Eah branch create a separate worfklow. Then test it, and re-integrate in the main.

Comment: Cloud Workflow should offer a better XP!! But congrats!

Comment: It seems that your issue has a workaround. Please post the resolution steps you had done as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

You may also submit a feature request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue.